If $A$ is $n \times n$ and $A^2 = A$, show that $A = A^T$ if and only if $\text{Null}(A^T) =\text{Range}(A - I)$.
As the title says, I am trying to show the following:

If $A$ is $n \times n$ and $A^2 = A$, show that $$A = A^T \iff \text{Null}(A^T) =\text{ Range}(A - I).$$

I showed the $\Longrightarrow$ direction, and now, I am trying to show the $\Longleftarrow$ direction. So far, I have shown an equivalent condition for $A = A^T$, namely that for all $x \in \text{Domain}(A) = \text{Domain}(A^T)$, we have
\begin{align}
Ax = A^Tx &\iff A^TAx = A^TA^Tx\\
&\iff A^TAx = (AA)^Tx\\
&\iff A^TAx = (A^2)^Tx\\
&\iff A^TAx = A^Tx.
\end{align}
Then, for any $v \in \text{Null}(A^T)$, we have $A^Tv = 0$ if and only if there exists $w \in \text{Domain}(A - I)$ such that $(A-I)w = v$. Then, we have
\begin{align}
(A-I)w = v &\iff A^T((A-I)w) = A^Tv\\
&\iff A^T(Aw - w) = 0\\
&\iff A^TAw - A^Tw = 0\\
&\iff A^TAw = A^Tw.
\end{align}
So, I have shown that the condition is met but for $w \in \text{Domain}(A - I)$ instead of in $\text{Domain}(A)$.

Is there a way to show that  $w \in \text{Domain}(A)$ from here? Is this the right way to go about the problem or is there an easier way? I got close to showing $\text{Null}(A) = \text{Null}(A^T)$ which would get me closer, but I wanted to check in here first on if this was the right approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
EDIT: Is $\text{Domain}(A) = \text{Domain}(A - I)$ automatically? Since they are both square matrices?

No need to write $\mathrm{Domain}$ because all of these maps act on $\mathbb{R^n}$!

That's what my gut was telling me, but thank you for the confirmation @SeanRoberson!

"So far, I have shown an equivalent condition for $A=A^T$": no, your 1st equivalence is only an implication. More shortly: if $A=A^T$ then (since $(A^2)^T=(A^T)^2$) $A^T=A^TA$, but you didn't prove the converse.

You're right @AnneBauval. My mistake.

If $\text{Null}(A^T) =\text{ Range}(A - I)$ then $\text{Null}(A^T) \supseteq\text{ Range}(A - I)$, which is equivalent to $A^T(A-I)=0$ i.e. $A^TA=A^T$, hence (by transposition) $A^TA=A$, and combining the two: $A^T=A$.
